# Защита от недобросовестных заказчиков?

Tags: любой-язык

в связи с первым моим заказом возник вопрос, какие актуальные способы защиты от кидалова(воровство продукта без оплаты) со стороны заказчика существуют?

О продукте: offline windows приложение.

Comment: Заключение договора.

Comment: Можно сделать триал версию программы

Comment: Где-то читал про интересный вариант защиты: со временем делать UI прозрачнее до 0 в триал версии

Comment: Вариант №1. Берите предоплату и киньте их сами. Как по вашему, что они сделают?.. Вот и делайте вы то же самое. Вариант  №2  найдите сильных инвесторов, пусть они сами разбираются с заказчиком. Если без шуток, то вариант №3: читайте комментарии №1 и №2

Answer (score 3):

По личному опыту посоветую два способа:

1. Покажите через демонстрацию продукт, выполните все требования по проверке функционала от заказчика. Дальше попросите его оплатить и после оплаты скидываете ему сам продукт.
2. Тестовая версия ( не всегда надежно + лишний гемор ).

PS: Если заказчик в Вашем городе, то не поленитесь заключить договор.
Так же есть много сайтов специализирующихся на таких сделках, к примеру один из таких https://freelancehunt.by/service/safe, к примеру на нем заказчик вначале платит, потом получает приложение и если его все устроило сайт отдает вам сумму, а если возникли проблемы все решается с помощью медиатора.